# How to install my package in Laravel 5.8? "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: laravel

I entered `composer require larabook/gateway` but the package was not be installed and I received the following error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Answer (score 3):

If `C:\php\php.ini` is your `.ini` file, then open it

Find this line

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and change it to this

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: in php 7.3.5, just uncomment.
    extension=fileinfo

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I was trying to create a Laravel project in PHP 7.4.

From your PHP location, go to `php.ini`, double click on it and look for `extension=php_fileinfo`. The latest version of PHP does not come with `.dll`, so if it is not there don't worry about it. After that, close the notepad, click on save and restart your cmd.

if you are using XAMPP, on the same line that runs Apache on port 80, 443, go to config click on it, navigate to PHP(php.ini) and carry out the same step. Once done, close the notepad file and restart. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

first run

```
composer update
```

then removing the semicolon from the line extension=php_fileinfo.dll of php.ini file

and rerun the

```
composer require larabook/gateway
```

Comment: thanks my bro. I did your orders but I got an error :Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.51 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.0.51) -> satisfiable by

Comment: - Installation request for league/flysystem (locked at 1.0.51) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.51].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

please help me thanks

Comment: and Iuse php7 and laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

It helped me!